# Spring security oauth/form authentication and CSRF - can they work together?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have gone through various examples of spring security and oauth authentication. I have it working, but not completely to my satisfaction. I am using java configuration.

Key problem is I want to apply oauth authentication only on certain urls. Lets say urls starting with "/api" needs to have oauth and urls starting with "/app" (or any other urls) need to have form authentiacation with its goodies like CSRF protection.

This does work in my current configuration, but "/app" urls loose CSRF protection. Digging deeper, it looks like ResourceServerConfig calls csrf.disable. So CsrfFilter class never gets a chance.

I have tried creating multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with varying order annotations which enables csrf, but somehow configuration extended from ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter always wins. I have even tried csrf request matcher with no luck.

Is it possible to (selectively) enable CSRF while using oauth? What is recommended best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended best practice (by me at least) is to always use CSRF (better safe than sorry, and if your client is a browser then it should be considered mandatory). So it is regrettable that the OAuth2 resource server switches it off, I agree. There are some changes underway in snapshots that a) make it easier to customize (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/315) and b) might lead to teh default changing as well (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/339). Until those issues are resolved. I think your only option is to not use `@EnableResourceServer` and write your own version of the same thing.